# Is there a simple way to map this 4x1 vector to this 4x2 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

Is there a simple way to map a vector like $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&0\\0&c\\0&d\end{bmatrix}$? I tried to do it via matrix multiplication but I couldn't figure it out. Maybe the Kronecker product? It seems like a simple question, so I wonder if anyone has run into something like this before. Thank you.

-DBL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it via matrix arithmetic via:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
b & 0 \\
0 & c \\
0 & d \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\b&0\\0&c\\0&d\end{bmatrix} $ itself is a well defined map from $M(4,1 )$ to $M(4,2)$. If you really want something written in mathematical language including kroneckers then do it like-

$\phi(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\\end{bmatrix})= \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\\end{bmatrix} .A $ wher $A=\begin{bmatrix}\delta_{a,b}\ \delta_{c,d}\\\end{bmatrix}$ is a $1\times 2 $ matrix such that $i.\delta_{k,l}=i$ if $i=k\ \text{or}\ l$ other wise $0$ where $i,k,l \in$ {$a,b,c,d$}

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.